# Issues uploading to Blob Storage c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

My task is to get some data from a postgres database and then write this to blob storage and then return the URI.

As the data contains up to 14 million rows, I have been using binary export to get the data out like so

```
            var fileText = new StringBuilder();
            fileText.AppendLine(string.Join(',', "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"));

            using var connection = CreateYellowBrickConnection();
            connection.Open();
            using var reader =
                connection.BeginBinaryExport(
                    $"COPY {tableName} (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4) TO STDOUT (FORMAT BINARY)");

            while (reader.StartRow() > 0)
            {
                fileText.AppendLine(string.Join(',', reader.Read<long>(), reader.Read<string>(), reader.Read<string>(), reader.Read<int>()));
            }

            return await _blobHelper.WriteToBlobAndReturnUri(application, retailerId, containerName, fileText, fileName);
```

This can take some time (obs depending on amount of data but up to say 14 mill rows). To upload the blob it calls

```
        public async Task<string> WriteToBlobAndReturnUri(string application, int retailerId, string containerName, StringBuilder fileText, string fileName)
        {
   
            try
            {
              
                GetBlobContainerService(application, retailerId, containerName);
                _azureServicesFactory.CloudBlobContainerService.GetCloudBlockBlobService($"{fileName}.csv");

                await _azureServicesFactory.CloudBlockBlobService.UploadTextAsync(fileText.ToString());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            return _azureServicesFactory.CloudBlockBlobService.Uri() + GetSasBlobToken(_azureServicesFactory.CloudBlockBlobService);
```

This all works fine locally with Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer (tried up to 14 mill rows) but once I put this on a testing environment with larger files say 300,000 KB (5 mil rows)  when it does the uploadtextAsync it basically fails silently and I get no response error messages in app insights.

I tried chunking this into blocs using basically the microsoft documentation

```
           //var blob = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
                //BlockBlobClient blobClient = blob.GetBlockBlobClient($"{fileName}.csv");
                ////ArrayList blockIDArrayList = new ArrayList();

                //byte[] buffer;

                //var bytesLeft = ms.Length - ms.Position;

                //while (bytesLeft > 0)
                //{
                //    if (bytesLeft >= blockSize)
                //    {
                //        buffer = new byte[blockSize];
                //        await ms.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, blockSize);
                //    }
                //    else
                //    {
                //        buffer = new byte[bytesLeft];
                //        await ms.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(bytesLeft));
                //    }

                //    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                //    {
                //        string blockID = Convert.ToBase64String
                //            (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));

                //        blockIDArrayList.Add(blockID);

                //        await blobClient.StageBlockAsync(blockID, stream);
                //    }

                //    bytesLeft = ms.Length - ms.Position;

                //}

                //string[] blockIDArray = (string[])blockIDArrayList.ToArray(typeof(string));

                //await blobClient.CommitBlockListAsync(blockIDArray);
```

But this was slower when timing locally. Is there anyway of making this more efficient and can anything be adjusted in the azure portal that help with this (just wondered if I am missing something) or is this just not a great implementation? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to use Append Blob Client and upload it in batches, for example 1000 rows

Comment: You can't expect this to happen 'all at one go', chunking or batching is necessary. Even when you export data from your PG db, you should export in batches. In your above code, what was your byte array `blockSize` - that also impacts the speed of upload.

Comment: I had a similar challenge and implemented it as shown in this post: https://blog.elmah.io/bulk-download-from-azure-blob-storage-with-c/. This is download, but you can use a similar approach for upload.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran. Yeah I thought chunking from PG db would be better but I was unsure how I would implement that as I am a bit blind on how many rows are in the table. Not sure how I would know what's been done and what's offset? I struggled to find any examples of doing this using binary export but if you could point in me in a direction that would be much appreciated.

In regards to block size I set at 1 million. I reduced it was slower and upped it but running it locally it was slower than just doing it all in one block.

Comment: block size of 1mil bytes is too high. when you do call new byte[blockSize], you are asking for a contiguous memory from OS, try with block size of 8KB, 16KB.  As for the export data from PG, you are looping through the rows, so after some 10k rows you could create a blob, upload it, and then repeat the process again.